# unity spawn enemies depending on Audio bursts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm trying to create a spawn system were enemies spawn depending on the music bursts. for example when a soft music is playing enemies spawn slowly and when a action part comes up enemies stars to spawn faster.

I'm really not good with Audio stuff so i just have this really general code where I'm trying to understand how it exactly works

Thanks in advance

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioVisualiser : MonoBehaviour {

private float[] m_spectrumData;
private int m_bufferSize = 1024;

// used for color animation
public Gradient g_gradient;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    m_spectrumData = new float[m_bufferSize];
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    GetComponent<AudioSource>().GetOutputData ( m_spectrumData , 0 );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < m_bufferSize; i++)
    {
        float x = i * 0.2f;
        float y =  m_spectrumData[i] * 10.0f;
        Debug.DrawLine (new Vector3 ( x ,0,0), new Vector3 (x,y , 0), g_gradient.Evaluate((float)i/m_bufferSize));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, there are one or more excellent asset store packages which do just this.

Comment: I tried to search but couldn't find anything :/ if you know any can you name it?

Comment: Damn - I can't find the "good one" ... what about https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19020 .. and .. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15679 .. and .. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30467

Comment: perhaps click "Scripting" (on the right column), and then add terms such as audio, beat, music etc ... I feel bad now I can't remember the "famous" one that was out there ... will keep looking!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and probably best) way to do this is to put points in your music that represent high action points in the music. This would put you in control and avoid accidental spawns that you don't want.